# EC2 instance stopped working after creating an Image

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, amazon-ami

I'm totally new to AWS.
I managed to have an instance that runs PHPMyAdmin.
then I created an image (EBS AMI) for this instant and could not connect any more to my
phpmyadmin interface.

I know it's really stupid, but I don't know why it happens.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure all needed services (e.g. ssh, Apache / nginx, MySQL) on your server get started when booting. If you create an AMI of your system AWS will shut down your server for the time the image creation takes place.

So ssh into your instance, [take a look at the running processes](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/) and start the ones which you miss.

Comment: Note there is an option to *not* reboot when creating the AMI, though there's a risk of corrupting any uncommitted data in flight.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking an image from the AWS console, all services will be stopped and server will be restarted for the image to be created. However, you need to restart all the services ex: mysql, apache etc.